# Why is File Mounted on Container via docker-compose not Accessible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

In my docker-compose file, I try to mount a file from the host into the docker container.

The docker-compose file I have something like this:

```
version "2"

services:
    myservice:
        image:  images/previmage:1.0.0
        volumes:
            - /opt/files/aaa.conf:/aaa.conf
```

After the service is started, I look at the contents at the root of the container using docker from the host:

```
sudo docker container exec myservice_1 ls /
```

The result of that ls command for the aaa.conf entry shows that it looks like it is there, but permissions are not what I expect:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root     6 Apr 11 2018 opt
-??????????  ? ?      ?        ?           ? aaa.conf
ls:  cannot access /aaa.conf:  Permission denied
```

Similarly, if I try other commands like 'cat aaa.conf', I get Permission denied.

I understand that permissions for the file need to be set on the host side.
On the host I made permissions both 755 and then 777, but I still get Permission denied.

Is this the expected behavior?

---

**Edit**  [running on AWS/EC2]

```
sudo docker container exec myservice_1 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

sudo docker container exec myservice_1 id -u
33016
```

Comment: what is your host OS?

Comment: Host is CentOS 7

Comment: please share the output of the following commands : `docker container exec myservice_1 cat /etc/os-release` , `docker container exec myservice_1 id -u` .. or better, share the real image that you are using to try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added the output of those commands to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, It's for SELinux ([Check this post](https://jaosorior.dev/2018/selinux-and-docker-notes/))

### Disable SELinux for a specific container

You can disable SELinux for a specific container by adding `--security-opt label:disable` to your `docker run` command:

```
docker container run --security-opt label:disable myservice_1
```

### Adding SELinux Rule (Recommended)

According to [this post](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/), You can also use this command to enable access to the files

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /path/to/volume
```

### Completely disable SELinux!

Not recommended, but also works:

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

Comment: Yes.  This worked for me.  I'm using docker-compose to start the containers, but the same option is available there.  Thanks for responding.